# InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>] in Lambda function python

Tags: python, function, lambda

I have a sentence with plain numbers and ordinal numbers and I wanted to convert ordinal digits to words like 2 nd to Second, 56 th to Fifty sixth.
I used the library num2words and below code works perfectly.

```
import num2words
text = "ordinal numbers are like as 42 nd, 67 th, and 5 th and plain numbers such as 1, 2, 3."
numbers = re.findall('(\d+ )[st|nd|rd|th]', text)
numbers
for n in numbers:
    ordinalAsString = num2words.num2words(n, ordinal=True)
    print(ordinalAsString)
    #forty-second
    #sixty-seventh
    #fifth
```

Now I want to create a lambda function such that,

```
sentence = "ordinal numbers are like as 42 nd, 67 th, and 5 th and plain numbers such as 1, 2, 3."
o/p sentence = "ordinal numbers are like as fourty-second, sixty-seventh, and fifth and plain numbers such as 1, 2, 3."
```

I wrote the function like this,

```
sentence = re.sub(r"(\d+ )[st|nd|rd|th]", lambda x: num2words.num2words(str(x), ordinal=True), sentence)
```

But that throws an error like,

```
InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]
```

What is wrong in the code?

Comment: Your regular expressions are different, is that the problem?

Comment: No regrex are same. @JacksonH

Comment: Looks to be related to this num2words issue: https://github.com/savoirfairelinux/num2words/issues/281

Comment: @NickODell if i want to make a correction in the library locally what I can do? Because it works fine with for loop. Is there any problem with Lambda function?

Comment: `str(x)` isn't going to give you the string you want; `x.group(1)` will. `[st|nd|rd|th]` also does not match what you think it does; it's equivalent to `[st|ndrh]`, with the `|` acting as a literal character, not an alternation operator.

Comment: @chepner thank you so much for the suggestion. I am now getting output like "ordinal numbers are like as forty-secondd, sixty-seventhh, and fifthh and plain numbers such as 1, 2, 3." after changing to `x.group(1)`

Comment: Yes, that's because the bracket expression isn't matching one of `st`, `nd`, `rd`, or `th`; it's matching one of `s`, `t`, `|`, `n`, `d`, `r`, or `h`.

Comment: Try `(?:st|nd|rd|th)`. `(st|nd|rd|th)` would work as well, but no use making it a capture group if you don't need to use the captured suffix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. Your regular expression isn't correctly matching the suffix, only the first letter of the suffix. `[st|nd|rd|th]` matches exactly one of the characters inside the brackets; duplicates are ignored, so it's equivalent to `[st|ndrh]`, with the `|` treated as a character to match like each of the letters. Use `r"(\d+ )(?:st|nd|rd|th)"` instead; the `|` inside the non-capture group `(?:...)` *does* work to separate the 4 patterns `st`, `nd`, `rd`, and `th`.
2. The callable passed to `re.sub` takes a `Match` object as its argument. You need to use its `group` method to extract the captured sting.  `lambda x: num2words.num2words(x.group(1), ordinal=True)`.

Comment: yes, it worked. Thanks a ton. For explanation and answer.